# Cassandra insert after delete fails

Tags: cassandra, consistency

In a specific case of deleting and reinserting rows to a table does not work as intended when replication factor is more than 1 (say 3).

I have tried using quorum for read as well as write and timestamp in the query with no success.

If the replication factor is set to 1, all works well. I have 5 nodes in my cluster.

Issue becomes visible when tried to read after the delete and insert operation. The read does not return rows that should have been inserted.

Could someone please share their thoughts on this?

**Edit:**

Following is what I have tried from code

Database create script:

```
DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS consistency_check;
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS consistency_check WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Cassandra': 3}  AND durable_writes = true;
USE consistency_check;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resource (
    id uuid,
    col1 text,
    col2 text,
    col3 text,
    col4 text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, col1)
);
```

C# Unit test code:

```
public class Resource
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
    public string Col4 { get; set; }
}


public class MyMappings : Mappings
{
    public MyMappings()
    {
        For<Resource>()
           .TableName("resource")
           .PartitionKey(u => u.Id)
           .Column(u => u.Id, cm => cm.WithName("id"))
           .Column(u => u.Col1, cm => cm.WithName("col1"))
           .Column(u => u.Col2, cm => cm.WithName("col2"))
           .Column(u => u.Col3, cm => cm.WithName("col3"))
           .Column(u => u.Col4, cm => cm.WithName("col4"));
    }
}

    //Following test fails always
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task DeleteInsert()
    {
        var table = new Table<Resource>(_session);
        _session.Execute("truncate resource");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            await table.Insert(new Resource { Id = id, Col1 = id.ToString(), Col2 = id.ToString(), Col3 = id.ToString(), Col4 = id.ToString() }).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        var data = (await table.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();
        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            await table.Where(e => e.Id == datum.Id).Delete().ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            await table.Insert(datum).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        var data1 = (await table.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("data length: {0}", data.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("data1 length: {0}", data1.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(data.Count == 10);
        Assert.IsTrue(data1.Count == 10);
    }
```

Comment: Are your clocks in sync?

Comment: @russs yes they are. It seems it works fine if i use plain cql instead of the mapper. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting the consistency level? If you use quorum for reads and writes, you shouldn't get this problem.

Comment: I tried quorum (although not shown in code), but shows the same result

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your running the inserts and deletes asynchronously - so the delete could have run before the inserts. In the case the delete clause will not be met and not rows will be deleted.

I am not super familiar with the C# async/await construct so i might be missing something